# How to make list of datetimes using rrule

Tags: python, icalendar, rrule

I am creating my own .ics parser.

I am using icalendar python module. It works great but I would like to get list of datetimes for events which have RRULE set.

I have starting date as datetime object instance and RRULE parsed like this:

```
CaselessDict({'FREQ': ['MONTHLY'], 'INTERVAL': [1], 'BYDAY': ['4TH']})
```

But I cannot figure out how to make a list of datetimes from these two things.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) library for generating `rrule`s, eg:

```
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MONTHLY

dts = list(rrule(MONTHLY, interval=10, byweekday=4, count=3))
# [datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 29, 15, 44, 45), datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 5, 15, 44, 45), datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 12, 15, 44, 45)]
```

Adjust arguments as needed.

Comment: So I have to cover all possibilities with some IFs and others? There can be a lot of them.

Comment: @Blaskovic why would you want to do that... You can pass in the variables from the dictionary that you have eg: `interval=your_CaselessDict['INTERVAL']` etc... You might have to create a mapping for the frequency though...

Comment: Because you can get something like this: WKST=SU;BYDAY=TU,TH
See: http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/rrule.html

Comment: @Blaskovic Okay.. so make sure you've got the constants imported `from dateutil.rrule import MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU` etc... and you map `TU` as text to the TU variable... so it ends up as `byweekday=[TU,TH]` etc...